# SHR command in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I am given a following code and I want to write the observations after every step. The code is:

```
MOV AL,15
MOV AH,0FFH
XOR AL,AL
MOV CL,3
SHR AX,CL
```

Now the only thing confusing me is the SHR command. I know that it will shift the value of AX 3 times but how will it do it?

Comment: What do you mean with 'how will it do it?' do you want an example diagram with gates on how a shift would work? Are you asking how it will fill the newly shifted inf bits?

Comment: The intermediate results (if you treat it as a sequence of 3 shifts) won't be observable in software. You'll observe only the final result and the appropriate number of clocks spent (8+4*CL clocks for 8086/8088). If that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Are you really asking about how AX aliases AH:AL?  If so, this is a duplicate of [x86 Calculating AX given AH and AL?](//stackoverflow.com/a/37275984)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will take the bit values that are in `AX` and shift them to the right.  For example, assuming:

- `AX` = 15
- `CL` = 3

15 in binary would be `00000000 00001111` in a 16 bit register (which `AX` is)
Shifting those bits to the right 3 places will result in: `00000000 00000001`

*(Please note:  I am not trying to use the values from your question since they appear to be a school assignment)*

The lowest three bits have been "shifted" into the bit-bucket or the void.  They are gone.